# Intellij Idea compile output including non-class file?

Tags: intellij-idea

I had a project that source code including non-class file in package(eg:.sql,.ftl). I want to generate output including them but the artifacts always contains class file. How can I include them?

It's a web application, and below is source structure(java code part):

```
src
  |
  main
     |
     java
        |
        package1
               |
               Class1.java
               Class2.java
               sql1.sql
               sql2.sql
               template1.ftl
```

The output only contains compiled class.

Comment: Post the structure of your project. Tell us if it's a Maven/Gradle project or not.

Comment: So apparently you're using Maven or Gradle, since your folder structure matches with their convention. Resources go in src/main/resources in a Maven or Gradle project. src/main/java is only for Java files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:
Project Structure->Module:at the bottom, Exclude files:*.java
Project Structure->Artifacts:Output Layout:add 'java' directory contents to classes